# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Property file not reading path

Tags: java, inputstream, properties-file

I am using eclipse on ubuntu 20.0
Here is my code to read property file:

```
public static String getProperty(String key) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        URL myURL = LoginProperty.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/global/resources/config.properties");
        InputStream input = myURL.openStream();
        properties.load(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        SendErrorsToAdmin.setMsg(LoginProperty.class.getClass().getCanonicalName(), e);
    }
    return properties.getProperty(key);
}
```

Here is my package hierarchicy:
[image: my eclipse project structure]

Here is the error:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [AdminLogin] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.openStream()" because "myURL" is null

How can I set path to `/global/resources/config.properties` in my `getProperty` method to read config.properties file?

Comment: Given your use of `src/main/java`, I assume you're using a build tool like Maven or Gradle, both of which use Maven's ["standard directory layout"](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) by default. In that directory layout, all resources (i.e., non-`*.java` files) should be under `src/main/resources`. Any directories under these "roots" function as packages. So, a class under `src/main/java/com/example` and a resource under `/src/main/resources/com/example` are in the same package: `com.example`.

Comment: When you've fixed the position of that resource as @Slaw suggested, you can simplify that to `try (InputStream input = LoginProperty.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties")) { properties.load(input);...`

Comment: @Slaw can I change directory structure in maven based web dynamic project

Comment: Why I can not give abolute or real path in maven based project?

Comment: The content is a resource and should be addressed as one in relation to the classpath. Nothing to do with files, 'real paths', the context etc. Personally, I always use url paths relative to the root - less room for error. That means `/foo....`

Comment: You can change the resource directory to `src/main/java` in Maven, yes. How to do that, I'll leave to you to look up. But note separating source files from resource files can help keep things organized. Also, what @g00se said is correct. You should not think of resources as "files". They're not files, particularly once packaged in a JAR file or JRT image. However, if you leave the resource root as `src/main/resources`, then any non-`*.java` files in `src/main/java` are _ignored_. They don't end up in the build output and thus don't end up on the class-path/module-path.